# Help needed with assignment

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Can I get some help with this:

> Write a module which as an input receives two matrices, the first matrix transforms in to the same matrix, but in the new matrix occur absolute values of the first, the second matrix makes the upper triangle and returns the product of these matrices. If the product is not possible it should print a message.

Comment: …and, what about your coding attempts?

Comment: well i made the first matrix and i know how to make the second , but to make the second i have  to make a matrix with absolute values of the first , which i don't know how . here is my code for the for the first matrix with negative values M = {};
For[i = -3, i <= -1, i++,
  redica = {};
  For[j = -3, j <= -1, j++,
   AppendTo[redica, i + j]
   ];
  AppendTo[M, redica]
  ];
M
MatrixForm[M] , can you help me ?

Comment: You should include your work-in-progress code in the question.  If people see you are making effort they are much more likely to do the same on your behalf.

Comment: As posed this question is not very attractive to those who could probably answer it. It asks them to do too much work for you -- work that you should have done before you posted the question. Your post would be much more attractive if you were to edit it to include: 1) a markdown formatted data set that can copied into _Mathematica_ for use as test data; 2) a markdown formatted _Mathematica_ expression or an image showing what you expect the final output to look like; 3) the code you have tried and and explanation of why you find it unsatisfactory.

Comment: We have had a lot of repeat questions with the same set of problems recently.  I have to wonder if your instructor is doing a good job of preparing you to complete these assignments.  The fact that you are writing in loops using `For` and `AppendTo` suggests to me that you have *not* had a good introduction to *Mathematica*.  If this assignment was specific to *Mathematica* as I believe I suspect that this class is not well structured.

Comment: I suppose it is indelicate to ask but what is the aim of the class?  Is use of *Mathematica* purely incidental or is it the focus of this segment of instruction?

Comment: this is for my discrete mathematics class , we don't have classes to explain how we could work in Mathematica they give us presentations where some functions are explained , but i don't know how to find the absolute values for the first matrix , because they didn't give us an explanation how to do it , so that is my question how to find the absolute values of the matrix i wrote above? Please help , I have to make this assignment to get a signаture

Comment: @TR19 Frankly that's a rough task.  *Mathematica* is very broad and the documentation is somewhat notorious for being difficult to quickly find things in.  Also without a background in functional programming or specific instruction you can easily end up with lengthy and inefficient code.  I posted an answer that should provide you the pieces of the puzzle that you need.

Answer (score 2):

In *Mathematica* [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) is a [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) function which means that it may be applied to a scalar, matrix, or tensor directly:

```
m1 = {{1, -8, 3}, {-1, -7, 9}, {-1, 0, -9}};

Abs[m1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 8, 3}, {1, 7, 9}, {1, 0, 9}}
> ```

[`UpperTriangularize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpperTriangularize.html) works like this:

```
UpperTriangularize[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 5, 6}, {0, 0, 9}}
> ```

Matrix product is implemented in [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html).

For writing this as "a module which as an input receives two matrices" see:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html

Finally a Q&A that is intended to steer users toward an efficient coding style:

- [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)